# On using formsauthentication in MVC5, button click is firing in different action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, razor, forms-authentication

My MVC5 project structure goes like this:

```
Project
  - App_Data
  - App_Start
      - RouteConfig.cs
  - Controllers
      - AccountController.cs
      - HomeController.cs
  - Views
      - Account
          - Index.cshtml
      - Home
          - Index.cshtml
      - web.config
  - Global.asax
  - Web.config
```

In View -> Account -> Index.cshtml is login page whose view for now is:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
        {
          <p>
              from Account
          </p>
          <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        }

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

AccountController code is:

```
  public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Account
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            if (true)  //assuming validation is true
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("test", false);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When user request this page, Index() method is called and when user click on Submit button, Login() method was to be fired.
Strangely, when I click on button Submit button, which is under form POST, it is hitting breakpoint in controller in Index() method instead of Login().

In inspecting the button, form tag had:

```
<form action="/Account/Login" method="post">
```

So I copied the URL and pasted in browser (http://localhost:55136/Account/Login), Index() method was called instead of Login(). However, if I remove code of formsauthentication from web.config and FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("test", false);, it works perfectly.

Web.config file for formsauthentication is:

```
<system.web>    
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Index" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" >
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear"></credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>    
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
```

My routing in RouteConfig.cs file is:

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

I am not understanding the behaviour of MVC now. This had never happened before. Why is MVC behaving this way? How can I redirect to Login() on Submit click?

Answer (score 0):

Your Web.config should have the  tag as shown below:

```
<system.web>...</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Can you post your full Web.config file?

Comment: <configuration><appSettings><add key="webpages:Version"value="3.0.0.0" /><add key="webpages:Enabled"value="false" /><add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /><add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled"value="true" /></appSettings><system.web>              <authentication mode="Forms"><forms  loginUrl="~/Account/Index" defaultUrl="~/Home/Index" ><credentials passwordFormat="Clear"></credentials>      </forms></authentication><authorization><deny users="?"/></authorization><compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" /><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" /></system.web></configuration>